# ical validates but Exchange server rejects

Tags: exchange-server, icalendar

I'm running out of ideas on what to change to make Exchange accept this ical. Unfortunately, we don't get any messages indicating what is wrong. Last modification was to remove RDATE tags. I thought that resolved the problem, but now this sample is being rejected

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Our/Product Identifier
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REPLY
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Chicago
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20151101T010000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0600
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20150308T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20150715T195751Z
DTSTAMP:20150715T200023Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20150715T200023Z
UID:04000CE00800000838BFD0010000008200E0007400000005B000B2561887101A8200000
 010045B0263C63E600CED48900C71000645920EFD
SUMMARY:Test new event 
LOCATION:office
DTSTART:20150715T200000Z
DTEND:20150715T210000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Foo;RSVP=TRUE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;ROLE=CHAIR:mailto:Foo@ba
 r.com
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

It passes all the online ical validators I've tried. This ical is generated in response to a meeting invitation. The meeting invitation is handled without a problem, except that this ical attachment is rejected by the exchange server.

Comment: have you tried changing `METHOD:REPLY` ? according to `RFC5546` `METHOD:REPLY` is to reply to a calendar invite.

Comment: That's what this is. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: I think we will be taking care of this by sending an active sync meeting response command and not sending an ical at all.

Comment: Another idea would be to try without the `VTIMEZONE` component

Comment: That was added because something else was failing without it - well maybe not replies. I may give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a REPLY to an invitation, then you should have an ATTENDEE property corresponding to the attendee on behalf of whom this REPLY is generated, and an ORGANIZER. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.3 for the full list of mandatory fields in a REPLY.

It looks like you are mixing the ORGANIZER and ATTENDEE here:

```
ORGANIZER;CN=Foo;RSVP=TRUE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;ROLE=CHAIR:mailto:Foo@bar.com
```

Assuming that Foo@bar.com is the attendee who is replying, you should instead have

```
ATTENDEE;CN=Foo;RSVP=TRUE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;ROLE=CHAIR:mailto:Foo@bar.com
```

and you should have an ORGANIZER with the same value as in the invitation.

You may want to show us the original invitation to which you are trying to reply to as there are other properties which are linked to the original invitation.

Comment: Thanks. I will look unto that.